# centering a logo in fluid layouts with a constraint on maximum logo size

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using yahoo's pure.css layout and I am having some small issues. I have a logo which would replace the heading and i want the logo to be fluid as well(The size changes with the bsize of the browser window).

I am currently using the following:

```
h1.logo{
  background-image: url('../images/LogoColor287x86.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  padding-top: 29.8%;
  height: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

This works but the result is not what i want. The above piece of CSS ensures that the logo occupies the maximum size available to it. But I want to to have a maximum size and centered. Say it should be a maximum size of 500px width even though the amount of space(width) available to it is 1000px.

Anyway to constrain the proportions.

Comment: use `max-width:500px` and try

Comment: the logo image starts repeating and instead of being centered, the whole container shifts to left.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m5ovf40f/

Answer (score 2):

For making the logo center use the property `background-position: center center`.

Also see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Saiyam/7fzfoy43/2/

Comment: Just use the link above to get the desired result

Comment: maybe a very noob question but where is .brand container?

Comment: This div structure might give some more info

Comment: Thanks. the issue was with some other css property which was adding some margin to the h1 tag. now it is fine

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you would like a background image to have a maximum size while remaining centered and scaling correctly when less space is available?

I accomplished this with nested elements - one positioned relative and taking the maximum space available to it. The nested element positioned absolute with the maximum values defined and then taking advantage of

```
background-size: contain;
```

See JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4bgcokux/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think some other divs are affecting the centering 
https://i.imgur.com/shzKI7o.png
The div structure is here

Comment: Can you post your exact HTML/CSS so that I can help a bit further? As long as the parent is positioned relative, and the child is absolute, this should be able to work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6actyqq2/1/ sorry. forgot the last time
Pure.css -> http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure.css

Comment: Great, thanks. Loaded in the yahoo pure.css, and updated one of your class names (logocontainer rather than just container) and updated the fiddle you sent: http://jsfiddle.net/6actyqq2/2/

Comment: Thanks. But i think your first answer is probably correct. The side menus css was adding some extra margin and hence it was being forced to the left.

Answer (score 0):

put your logo inside a div with css `text-align: -webkit-center;`

HTML:

```
<div class="header">   
<h1 class="logo"></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
   background-image: url('https://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
   background-size:contain;
   padding-top: 29.8%;
   max-width: 50%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header {
   text-align: -webkit-center;
   width:100%;
}
```

Hope it helps you...